# Parameter pack in overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution, parameter-pack

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template<class T>
void f(const T& a, const T&b) { std::cout << "#1"; }

template<class ...T>
void f(T&& ...a) { std::cout << "#2"; }
 
int main() { f(0, 1); } // prints #2
```

I wonder why #2 is considered more specialized during overload resolution. The following are my reasoning for #1 being more specialized.

Following the rules for determining the [partial ordering of function templates](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.partial), we first perform deduction for transformed #1 against original template #2. From [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.func.order#3),

> To produce the transformed template, for each type, non-type, or
> template template parameter (including template parameter packs
> (13.7.4) thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template
> respectively and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter
> in the function type of the template.

Suppose the unique synthesized type for transformed #1 is for `T` is `U`. Then during template argument deduction, for both arguments `a` and `b`, we have `P = T&&` and `A = const U&`. Following the deduction rules, we get `T = const U&` for both arguments. The deduction succeeds, so #1 is at least as specialized as #2.

Now we perform deduction for transformed #2 against original template #1. According to [this paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#10.2):

> If the parameter-declaration corresponding to P_i is a function
> parameter pack, then the type of its declarator-id is compared with
> each remaining parameter type in the parameter-type-list of A. Each
> comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the
> template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack.
> During partial ordering, if A_i  was originally a function parameter
> pack:
>
> - if P does not contain a function parameter type
>   corresponding to  A_i  then  A_i  is ignored;
> - otherwise, if  P_i  is not a function parameter pack, template argument deduction
>   fails.

In our case, our first argument `A_1` was originally a function parameter pack, but `P_1` is not a parameter pack. So template argument deduction fails, and #2 is not at least as specialized as #1. So #1 is more specialized.

Where does my reasoning break down?

Comment: #2 is exact match, whereas #1 "add" `const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Repost the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder why #2 is considered more specialized during overload resolution.

That consideration would happen later.

The selection is already be done from "previous" criteria:

From [Best_viable_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function):

> 1. there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

And then from [Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences)

> c) or, if not that, both S1 and S2 are binding to a reference parameter to something other than the implicit object parameter of a ref-qualified member function, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue while S2 binds an lvalue reference to an rvalue

> e) or, if not that, both S1 and S2 are binding to a reference parameters only different in top-level cv-qualification, and S1's type is less cv-qualified than S2's.

Comment: Why isn't it this [earlier rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.3): S1 and S2 include reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference

Comment: I miss it... :-)